# How do you filter out or remove null values, so that words with no synonym match do get displayed?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($unique as $value) 
{
    $getsynonym = "\"".$value."\"";

    $synonym_result = mysqli_query($connect2,
        "SELECT synonyms.* 
         FROM words 
         LEFT JOIN synonyms  
             ON synonyms.word_id = words.word_id  
         WHERE word = ".$getsynonym."
         LIMIT 15"
     );

    echo "</br></br> SYNONYM FOR: ".$value." ";
    echo "{";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($synonym_result)):  
        print_r($row['synonym']);
        echo "|";   
    endwhile; 

    echo "}";
}
```

**Here are the actual results:**

```
SYNONYM FOR: Don't {}

SYNONYM FOR: Miss {Frau|Fraulein|Mistress|Mlle|Mme|Mmes|dame|dona|donna|lady|madam|madame|mademoiselle|mem-sahib|mesdames|}

SYNONYM FOR: Our {}

SYNONYM FOR: Next {adjacent|adjoining|after|after all|after that|afterward|afterwards|appendant|behind|below|bordering|by|closest|coming|connecting|}
```

**I want to not show values that have no synonyms! So it looks like this instead:**

```
SYNONYM FOR: Miss {Frau|Fraulein|Mistress|Mlle|Mme|Mmes|dame|dona|donna|lady|madam|madame|mademoiselle|mem-sahib|mesdames|}

SYNONYM FOR: Next {adjacent|adjoining|after|after all|after that|afterward|afterwards|appendant|behind|below|bordering|by|closest|coming|connecting|}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [*mysqli_num_rows*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check you actually get the results rows,

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($synonym_result) > 0){
    echo "</br></br> SYNONYM FOR: ".$value." ";
    echo "{";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($synonym_result)): 
       print_r($row['synonym']);
       echo "|";
    endwhile; 
    echo "}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to check in the query if the number of synonyms is greater then `0`.

```
SELECT synonyms.*, COUNT(synonyms.word_id) AS synonymsNumber
FROM words 
LEFT JOIN synonyms  
   ON synonyms.word_id = words.word_id  
WHERE word=".$getsynonym." 
AND synonymsNumber > 0
LIMIT 15"
```